# Remote Desktop Protocol for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, windows-update, remote-desktop-services

Currently we're having formatting issues when printing from a Windows 2008 server via TS Easy Print which we don't see when printing from Windows Server 2008 R2.

Clients are running windows 7 with a mix of RDP 7.1 and 8.0.

The windows 2008 server is running RDP 6.1.
The windows 2008 R2 server is running RDP 8.0.

My theory is that it's the server's protocol version affecting whether users have formatting issues. See [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041729/reports-are-printed-without-margins) which prompted this thought.

I've found a lot of upgrades for various OS client's RDP versions, but so far can't find an option to upgrade the Windows 2008 server version of the protocol, though can't find anything saying which RDP versions are available for each server version.

**Question**

Is there an update to upgrade Windows Server 2008 (R1)'s Remote Desktop Protocol beyond 6.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer just your question...sadly no.  While you can upgrade a TS client's RDP version, the server version is dependent on the underlying OS installed and isn't upgradeable outside of upgrading the OS itself.  Meaning while the RDC (remote desktop client)version's can be upgraded on a machine...the RDS (remote desktop services) is dependent on the OS installed and cannot be upgraded.